# Error with insert into sql server database with php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database, insert

I have error with insert multi column data into SQL Server database with PHP

php Code:

```
<?php
    $serverName = "GHAREBAGHI\sqlexpress, 1433";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"PwKara", "UID"=>"test","PWD"=>"100100");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn ) {
        echo "Connection established.<br />";
    } else {
        echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    $tsql= "INSERT INTO Requests
  (EMP_NO ,SubmittedDate ,Type ,StartDate ,EndDate ,StartHour ,EndHour
,Duration ,SubmittedByEmployeeID ,OperationsID ,Description ,CurEmp_NO ,AcceptCode ,IsWardenCheck ,RequestStatus ,IOStatus ,CurSection)
VALUES
(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $para = array("93229 ,'2016-10-19 09:23:48.850' ,54 ,'2016-10-19 09:23:48.850' ,'2016-10-19 09:23:48.850' ,2359 ,2359 ,2 ,83229 ,3 ,'php test' ,8813 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,6");

    if (!sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $para)){
        die('Error: ' . sqlsrv_errors());
    }
    echo "1 record added"; 
?>
```

Result: [php error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJcv3.png) (Array to string conversion on line 52)

The line that the error was pointed out to him:

`die('Error: ' . sqlsrv_errors());`

Comment: Please read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `$para = array` why are those in `" .... "` ? This is not array, this is string. Delete `"` on both sides.

Comment: you can use `var_dump($var);` you will get what type of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$para = array` why are those in `" .... "` ? This is not array, this is string. Delete `"` on both sides. It will be like:

```
$para = array(93229, '2016-10-19 09:23:48.850', 54, '2016-10-19 09:23:48.850', '2016-10-19 09:23:48.850', 2359, 2359, 2, 83229, 3, 'php test', 8813, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6);
```